# jQuery plugin with flowing divs (blocks)?

Tags: jquery, plugins, grid

I am looking for a specific jQuery plugin that had a grid of blocks that flowed/animated to their new positions when the browser window was made smaller/larger. I know I've seen this before but I cannot for the life of me find it anywhere. Anybody know what its called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Masonry? http://masonry.desandro.com/